# Moving wordpress to an unknown outlet

Tags: server, migration

I have some wordpress websites on one server that I want to download. The problem is I don't know what url or what server I am moving it to. The problem is I do want the original to work. Suggestions on what I should do?

[This Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) suggests I already know where I am moving the wordpress... Suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about it - just download all databases and files.

And if you're uploading them to the new server, change the wp-config files and run the following queries on the databases:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.example.com', 'http://www.newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.example.com','http://www.newurl.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.example.com/', 'http://www.newurl.com');
```

If your permalinks are still not working, delete the .htaccess file, and go to Settings->Permalinks and click save to create the .htaccess file.

Comment: No entirely different server, entirely different domain. It might be local or through some provider I'm not sure yet.

Comment: OK Thanks, since I am not 100% if this will work I won't give it a "answer" mark yet. Enough upvotes i'll give it a check.

Comment: you're welcome. this is exactly what i always do if i move my wp sites from localhost to online server - and it always works like a charm. no prob for the 'answer' mark!

Comment: It took awhile but this was the easiest, safest bet. Worked like a charm thanks!

Comment: just for future reference: since a couple of months i'm using the wonderfull backupbuddy  plugin for all wp migration - it's not free, but it saves me loads of time - and offers lots of other pretty interesting features (eg. automatic offsite backups)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read through this article before going ahead with any search and replace in the database:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Doing a basic SQL replace takes no account of serialised arrays and could mess up plugins and other settings. This might be overkill, but if you have a large site with several plugins this could come avoid problems later.

I personally always use this little tool. It's also handy because you can simply copy it to your wordpress folder and run the update from your browser.

Comment: Works like a charm, indeed!

Answer (score 1):

The following links should guide you apart from what @ptriek  has suggested.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database

You can also try setting WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME in wp-config.php file.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29
http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Blog_address_.28URL.29

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
```

Comment: Right I thought about hardcoding it like that (with define I mean) but I didn't want the ugly long url that came with it :S